# cannot find inApp purchase option in app summary

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I have create app with in app purchase. It is mandatory to upload it for review but my problem is that i cant find option in app summary like this image.[image]

Above image is from another app where i found it but in my current app it is not visible.

I have enabled in App purchase in my app id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I had selected "YES" for Hosting content with apple but when I changed it to "NO", then my problem got solved. Now it shows option for in App Purchase in App Summary.

Answer (score 2):

Visit [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide.pdf) for the correct information and configure correctly.

Comment: @codeGeek, avoid link only answers, the reason being, only the link is broken, the answer becomes useless...

Answer (score 0):

Check App Identifier you are using for your application. If you have enabled InApp purchase than only option will be available.

If you haven't enabled yet than:

- go to App IDs
- Select your App Id
- click on edit & check InApp purchase

Hope it'll help to you.

Comment: plz read question carefully i have already stated that i enabled it.